# How do I learn how to write QA test scripts for software products?

Tags: unit-testing

Writing Quality Assurance course test scripts for software products is a critical part of ensuring the quality and reliability of the software. Test scripts are sets of instructions that QA testers follow to verify that the software functions correctly and meets its requirements.

Comment: This is rather broad and I'm not really sure what you're asking about here. Can you narrow the question down to specific technologies or domains? Thanks. QA test scripts for web apps in Playwright is totally different than desktop or mobile QA test scripts.

Comment: Normally in software we just jump in and flail around until we get better at it.

Comment: You can't prove a negative: you can not prove the absence of bugs. You can reduce bugs, but doing it at a late stage is too late. The software devs need to adopt practices that reduce defects. They need to test their own code. Also, scripts should be automated, humans should be un-scripted using intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Think like the user from hell.

- Check that it dose what it should. (knowledge of the spec is needed for this one)
- Check that you can achieve the goals of a user, easily. (user insight is needed for this one)
- Check that it does not break, including giving wrong results (some sort of insight of what can go wrong in the software/hardware is useful for this one).

Depending on which of the roles that you will be doing. You may benefit from:

- Legal knowledge: it does not do what you want, but it meets the spec, so hand over the moneys.
- Business/user experience, that is having a deep knowledge of the users of the system. What task are they trying to get done. What is the easiest way to get it done.
- Programming experience. I would leave these tests to the programmers.